# Moving child resource to another parent in REST

Tags: rest

I have a REST service.

And now I need to have functionality to move some child resources from one parent to another, for example move a book from one author to another.

My variant is:

```
POST /api/books/x/moveto/y
```

But how to create such architect the RESTful way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a REST point of view, URLs should be used to locate the resources rather than expressing operations. To express operations, the [existing HTTP verbs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3) should be used.

Looks like your "*move*" operation is all about *replacing* the author of the book.

And the [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) method seems to be the way to go:

> [**4.3.4. PUT**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4)
>
> The `PUT` method requests that the state of the target resource be
> created or replaced with the state defined by the representation
> enclosed in the request message payload. [...]

So, you can have an endpoint like the following:

```
PUT /api/books/{bookId}/author
```

And the request payload will contain a representation of the new author.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case updating the author as suggested in Cassio's answer is a good solution. For less obvious "actions" I use `PATCH` endpoints. Consider archiving a book:

```
PATCH /api/books/{bookId}/archive
```

The intent is obvious -- archive the book with this identifier. For more complex actions, include a body or use a query string parameter. For instance, moving a book out of one category and into another (assume a book can have 0-many categories):

```
PATCH /api/books/{bookId}/move

{
    fromCategoryId: 100,
    toCategoryId: 200
}
```

Or:

```
PATCH /api/books/{bookId}/move?fromCategoryId=100&toCategoryId=200
```

In the end, IMO, what matters most is readability and consistency. There is not necessarily a "right" way to do this sort of thing.

Comment: PUT has to be idempotent. If a book is moved from 100 to 200, can it be moved again from 100 to 200 when the book is already at 200? I think you would want POST.

Comment: Fair enough, `PATCH` is probably better than `PUT` and `POST`.